# Relative path changing with drag and drop on batch file

Tags: batch-file, relative-path

This is my code, I drag and drop several images at one to compress all of them.

```
if [%1]==[] goto :eof
:loop
start %~dp0ImgCompress.exe %1
shift
if not [%1]==[] goto loop
```

It's works well for the first file, but at the 2nd and beyond the relative path (%~dp0) becomes the relative path of the files I drag and drop.  My thought is that the %~dp0 was the relative path of the executing file.  Any idea how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path to your batch file is %0. Shift makes that %1 becomes %0. To solve you problem save %~dp0:

```
set mydir=%~dp0
```

And use it later:

```
start %mydir%ImgCompress.exe %1
```